# How to declare a generic constraint that is a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have a two generic abstract types: `Entity` and `Association`.

Let's say `Entity` looks like this:

```
public class Entity<TId>
{ 
//...
}
```

and `Association` looks like this:

```
public class Association<TEntity, TEntity2>
{
//...
}
```

How do I constrain Association so they can be of any Entity?

I can accomplish it by the following:

```
public class Association<TEntity, TId, TEntity2, TId2>
     where TEntity : Entity<TId>
     where TEntity2: Entity<TId2>
{
//...
}
```

This gets very tedious as more types derive from `Association`, because I have to keep passing down TId and TId2. Is there a simpler way to do this, besides just removing the constraint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem is usually solved by having your generic class (`Entity<TId>`, in this case) inherit from a common *non-generic* class.

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{

}

public class Entity<TId> : EntityBase
{

}
```

This will allow you to do:

```
public class Association<TEntity, TEntity2>
    where TEntity : EntityBase
    where TEntity2 : EntityBase
{

}
```

**Edit**

If having them inherit from a common class is an issue, then this could be easily done with an interface as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'd already come to the conclusion that an interface would suit my needs best, except I need to readjust my interfaces to have a non-generic base! I was hoping there'd be a neat language trick, but alas...

Comment: @HackedByChinese: I'm sure it's something that could be added, but given that there's an existing workaround that's both simple and 100% effective (without sacrificing any functionality), it's probably not likely that we'll be seeing anything akin to `TEntity<?>` any time soon ;)

Comment: Darnit. Fell on this while looking for a similar answer... Given that one can call "typeof(myGenericClass<>)", I was hoping that a constraint could be defined in a similarly open fashion.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Id` types are important inside the `Association` definition, you could create an enclosing "context":

```
public static partial class EntityIds<TId1, TId2> {

    public class Association<TEntity1, TEntity2>
      where TEntity1 : Entity<TId1>
      where TEntity2 : Entity<TId2>
    {
      // ...
    }

}
```

This way, the `Association` class declaration is still intelligible, and it retains the necessary type arguments for its type parameters.

A factory method could help you with the normal case:

```
public static class AssociationFactory {
  public static EntityIds<TId1, TId2>.Association<Entity<TId1>, Entity<TId2>> Create<TId1, TId2>(/*params...*/) {
    return new EntityIds<TId1, TId2>.Association<Entity<TId1>, Entity<TId2>>(/*params...*/);
  }
}
```

It that looks like too much, and if you don't have entity specializations, you could model the association differently:

```
public class Association<TId1, TId2>
{
  // ... 
  Entity<TId1> Entity1 { get; set; }
  Entity<TId2> Entity2 { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```